# Can javascript remove, create script or style DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, dom

Just like that. Can javascript remove, create script or style tags? How? *The thought makes me feel weird.*

**EDIT** *a day later*

I mean if javascript is capable of reproducing, it is a organism; and if a script can multiply itself then it might cause over-population. On the other hand, if it can kill another script then it is a murder; and if it can kill itself then it is a suicide. That's what I mean *how*, don't you think it was a weird thought?

Comment: `How?` By using the DOM API provided by the host environment. Start by learning about [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/learn/javascript).

Comment: *"The thought makes me feel weird."* Maybe a cup of tea helps.

Comment: use jquery. its easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) can create any element you'd like:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
var style = document.createElement('style');
var wat = document.createElement('wat');
```

To remove a DOM node, you simply need to select it first:

```
var script = document.querySelector('script');
script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
```

---

Addressing the update:

> if javascript is capable of reproducing, it is a organism

That is incorrect. Organisms are not defined by their ability to replicate.

> if a script can multiply itself then it might cause over-population.

If you're using a loose definition of population to mean the number of occurrences of a particular script, then yes, a script can "over populate" its environment to the point of self-destruction; otherwise known as "running out of memory".

> On the other hand, if it can kill another script then it is a murder (sic)

As the definition of murder is "the unlawful premeditated killing of one human being by another", that statement is obviously false. [The programming jargon for "kill" as in "killing a process" (i.e. "turn off") should not be confused with "kill" as in "killing a person" (i.e. "slay")](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/ambiguity).

> don't you think it was a weird thought?

This is a subjective question and is generally discouraged on StackOverflow. I think that by misusing, and misunderstanding programming jargon it is easy to construct strange statements. As far as "suggesting something supernatural or uncanny", I do not find the concept of script replication or execution management to be mysterious.

Comment: [on a related note the ability to build `<script>` elements means that JavaScript can be used to automatically build and execute quines](http://jsfiddle.net/97c3m/).

Answer (score 0):

You  can create any element by `document.createElement('tag name here')` but you also need to add it to the DOM.

Another way, which I don't recommend is `document.write("<script></script>");`